# StackOverFlow Delay

Tags: c

While executing the following program in Visual Studio 2012 Console App:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int integer1, integer2, sum;

    char str[5];
    scanf("%s",str); /* Try to enter 10 chars */
    printf("%s\n",str);

    printf( "Enter first integer\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &integer1 );

    printf( "Enter second integer\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &integer2 );

    sum = integer1 + integer2;
    printf( "Sum = %d\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

It throws an exception "StackOverFlow" and this is obvious because of the statement:

```
scanf("%s",str); /* Try to enter 10 chars */
```

My question is: Why does the program continue the execution (by printing the str string, asking for entering the 2 integers, sum them and print the result also) even though the exception should have happened earlier?

Comment: Just a note: I'm pretty sure C doesn't use exceptions. That could be related.

Comment: @Sam: hardware exceptions are not the same thing as C++ exceptions

Comment: It depends on what bytes in the memory will be overwritten by the superfluous input. You can reorder your code randomly, add some variables, call some functions, and it will behave differently. From programmer point of view it's random.

Comment: Ya, sure. My question is: Why this exception (H/W) signal is not sent to the process just when it happened? Why this signal is delayed till the program is over ???

Comment: This code ensure that the overflow happened in line:
scanf("%s",str); /* Try to enter 10 chars */

I do not know why it is delayed??

Comment: "it happend" - that's the problem with your reasoning. From machine's point of view nothing has happened yet - just some bytes were changed, just like they do all the time any code is running. The problem occurs when these bytes will be used - for example taken off the stack to return from a function.

Comment: @PaulR, thanks. I guess I'm too caught up in application programming languages these days!

Comment: Thanks Guys.

@BartoszKP can you elaborate more on how the stack violation is noticed just after returning from main NOT when it actually happened (at the scanf statement)

Comment: @Mustafa You have everything in amdn's answer. Stack is used to store the address of the instruction to execute after the function has finished (in this case - main). Corrupting the stack corrupts this address, so the execution jumps to an invalid memory region. There are many possibilities then - random processor instructions get executed, or nowadays - a part of memory guarded by OS is reached and prohibited from executing.

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks. When I posted my reply to you, amdn was not yet replied to my question. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack grows down, from high addresses to lower addresses.  A CPU register, the *stack pointer* keeps track of the *top of stack* - which is in reality at the lowest address, because the stack grows towards lower addresses.  The compiler looks at your function (main in this case) and looks to see how much *automatic* storage it needs, that is, storage for local variables.  It generates code to decrement that *stack pointer* by the amount of local storage needed by your function.  When the function gets called the caller pushes on the stack the return address (decrementing the stack pointer) and then branches to the called function, which in turn decrements the stack pointer (creating a *stack frame*) to make room for local variables.

If a program overflows the local variables (as yours did) it is likely to trash the return address.  Since the stack grew *down* towards lower addresses, writing beyond the stack frame (towards *higher* addresses) will overwrite older stack frames (your caller, and the caller's caller, etc).

Although main() is the first function to be called in your program, there is already an active *stack frame*, corresponding to main()'s caller, which is the runtime environment.

Any side effects of trashing the stack (like overwriting the return address) won't be noticed until your function, *main()* in this case, tries to return.  What happens then is anyone's guess.  If the return address was overwritten with a value that points to a location on the stack, the CPU will branch there, this is a classic exploit by malicious code that takes advantage of buffer overflows with buffers allocated on the stack.

These links are helpful in understanding stack based buffer overflow:

http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow3.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack

Recent microprocessors provide a security feature that prevents execution of data, the CPU would raise an exception as soon as your program attempts to return to a corrupted address that points to data (like the stack).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit

[image]

Comment: This is just the answer that I need. It was up to the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because C doesn't check everything (anything?). Your long string has scribbled on the stack, which when the function returns the stack corruption is noticed.

It's worth noting that [safe versions of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx) `scanf` type functions should always be used.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how the stack violation is noticed just after returning from main NOT when it actually happened (the scanf statement)

Answer (score 1):

In C, code can't throw exceptions. Also, `scanf()` doesn't check the stack.

What probably happens is that Visual Studio creates the environment for your program, including setting up the stack. While it does that, it fills the stack with a pattern.

When `main()` returns, the pattern is checked. Only at that time, the C runtime will notice that you trashed the stack.

Conclusion: Never use the unsafe versions of `scanf()` and `sprintf()`. The runtime might catch the error but it will do it too late and even when you get an error message, that won't help you one bit to find out when it happened.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how the stack violation is noticed just after returning from main NOT when it actually happened (the scanf statement)

Comment: C functions don't check the stack. They assume that everything works correctly and stack trashing doesn't happen. The only way to notice a trashed stack in normal C code is when the return address is overwritten and your code crashes with an illegal memory access. So tools like Valgrind instrument the code to put more bytes on the stack when functions are called.